# Give sudo permission to all simple pip installed packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo

On my ubuntu server, some of the installed python packages are simple `pip install` some are `sudo pip install`. Is there any way I can give `sudo` permission to simple `pip install`?

Note: There is around 250+ package. Installing one by one is quite hectic.
Please help.

Comment: Have you considered the impact of that change?

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for pointing that out. Since I am new I don't know want can go wrong.

Comment: `sudo pip install package1 package2` or create a requirents.txt file with your packages and run `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `requirements.txt` file through cmd: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
it'll list all the python installed packages in you're system to that file. once you got the all packages install using either sudo or normal pip.

- with sudo: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`
- with out sudo : `pip install -r requirements.txt`

i hope this will help you.